# Elegant way to convert date string from short to long format

Tags: python, replace

Let suppose that I have a date string like

```
09 NOV 2012
```

and I want to transform it to

```
9 November 2021
```

Which is the fastest and more elegant way to do that in Python? Of course I can create a dict like

```
{ "JAN": "January", ... "DEC": "December" }
```

make a loop, strip leading zero from day, and use replace() on month, but I am looking for a compact elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `strptime()` and `strftime()` from `datetime.datetime` ([check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

```
>>> spam = '09 NOV 2012'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(spam, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%d %B %Y')
'09 November 2012'
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @NizamMohamed in the comments - use `%e` in the format string for day without leading zero, but with extra space. You may use `str.strip()` to remove it.

```
>>> datetime.strptime(spam, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%e %B %Y')
' 9 November 2012'
```

Comment: `%e` for day of month without a leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import re

rep = { "JAN": "January", "NOV": "November" }
text = '09 NOV 2012'
# use these three lines to do the replacement
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.items()) 
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
text = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], text)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
'09 November 2012'
```

Comment: This ignores locale. Bad!